# Do an action/show text when in the specific place (Android studio)

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, android-gps

I'm a begginer android apps developer. I was wondering if there is some kind of way to make app do some kind of action or show a text message when user is in a specific place or in some kind of radius where the text message can be displayed? To be exact i'm talking about that when the programs gps recognises that user is in a specific place, app does some kind of action. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do so.

You could do that by getting specific response from an API. (for example Google Places APi).

You can find more information about this API [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro).